# Prevent/Allow the importing of static files by Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, import

I'm building a single page application and importing .js files dynamicly when needed on the client using `` await import(`./scripts/script.js`) ``.

**Proplem**

is that the scripts folder has files for guests, members and admins, so now any one can import those files from the browser console and see or run the code in it, **NOTE** i dont have anything to hide in those files, but for example, i still want to prevent a guest from just imorting member or admin files at will.

NOTE: we're using Node.js for the backend)

**Question**

Can the server detect/intersept the incoming request for the file from the browser when `` import(`./scripts/script.js`) `` is called ?
If not, is there any other way ?

**Clarification**

I just need a way to request js/css files from the server and have the server decide whether to send me the requested files or not.

Comment: You have two very different questions here. Do you expect a solution to #2 to also solve the problem #1 by checking user authorization on the server-side?

Comment: not necessarily, i just need a way to request js/css files from the server and have the server decide whether to send me the requested files or not.

Comment: You need to implement some kind of authorization scheme. There are many tutorials on how to do that on the internet...

Comment: I have user authorization already, but i dont know how to send a static file from the server and have the client run it, i tried ```fetch(somepath)``` but it returned an object containg the file data as a string and i didnt know what to do with it..